# How do I add a random string to messagebox.showinfo?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script that is working well. The only thing I would like to add is a random output from an array in the messagebox.showinfo. I have tried creating the array and referencing the array using random.choice("array") where "Array is the varialbe for the list. The script runs well, it just does not pull an item from the array as expected. Any ideas? or am I going about this the wrong way? Does tkinter have a random generator option?

```
    messagebox.showinfo("Totals", random.choice(random_message))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this piece of code might help:

```py
from tkinter import messagebox
import random

random_message = ['Variant 1', 'Variant 2', 'Variant 3']
messagebox.showinfo("Totals", random.choice(random_message))
```

Please, notice how the libraries are imported - `import random` is used instead of `from random import *`. In the `random_message` list, you can choose any strings.